# Powershell: Function that adds data every time it is run from a function

Tags: function, powershell, join, append

I know I'm doing something wrong but I am stuck... I am connecting to a Cisco device over serial, then each time I send a command, I can read the output from by typing `$port.ReadExisting()`. I need to be able to run many commands, let the buffer fill, then get the output from the port. I have to check to make sure that there's something to read first, which is why I put it in a function to be able to be called over and over.

Every time it is called, the `$COMReply` is wiped out. How can I take what is in `COMReply`, add `$port.ReadExisting()`, and have `COMReply` spit out all of what was written?...

```
Function WaitForReply {
    while ($port.BytesToRead -gt 0){
        $COMReply += $($port.ReadExisting()) + "`n"
    }
}
```

Also, how should I call my function?... should I just call it with: `WaitForReply`? or should I set a variable equal to it with `$AllMyReplies = WaitForReply`?

Comment: Can you show where you define/assign to `$COMReply` initially?

Comment: I think what Mathias is getting at is that you are likely running into scope issues here. Functions run in a child scope, so things that are defined in a function are lost when the function completes, but if you define the variable in the parent scope, or explicitly define a scope you should be fine. You may want to just change all references from `$COMReply` to `$script:COMReply`, which should resolve issues you're seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to PowerShell's copy-on-write behavior when interacting with a variable in a different [*scope*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes).

You'll find that you can write to the `$COMReply` variable defined outside the function if you prefix the variable name with the `script:` or `global:` scope qualifiers (ie. `$script:COMReply += ...`).

... but the **real** way to solve this problem is to avoid *reading from*, and more importantly **writing to**, variables across scope boundaries.

To avoid that, you'll want to:

1. Declare all the input you need as parameters
2. Output the results as-is, instead of writing to a variable outside of the function

If we do that, we end up with something like this:

```bsh
function Wait-ForReply($Port){
    while($Port.BytesToRead -gt 0){
        $Port.ReadExisting()
    }
}
```

This gives our function a nice *clean* surface - the function doesn't depend on being able to discover `$port` from the calling scope, and `$COMReply` is unaffected by what goes on inside the function.

Now you can add or concatenate to `$COMReply` in the calling scope, by simply doing:

```
$COMReply += Wait-ForReply -Port $port
```

Comment: So I tried changing it to what you had suggested and it is only capturing some of the information... It looks like it's only the first time there's a reply

Comment: So it turns out that it was because I had another function that was calling running `foreach`. This meant that while your recommendation fixed the problem for everything outside of that, as soon as it was called in the `foreach` function, it just "forgot" the bulk of what it had done and what I'm actually interested in. As soon as I just put the code inline with the rest of the script, I got what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Where would you add the `$COMReply` line in this context? I'm trying to get the whole picture here, and don't see how to implement this, from the info given. I mean where and how to you get to print the data?

Comment: @not2qubit looks like OP might have remove some comments on the original question, but I think `$port` is a [`SerialPort` instance](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/writing-and-reading-info-from-serial-ports/) and `$COMReply` is just a string, so just define it as `$COMReply = ''` any time before you start assigning to it.